# Vite manifest not found

Tags: php, laravel, vite, laravel-9

I Working on project that working with `laravel 9` and `Vite` with  `laravel-vite`,

In Dev environment all thing working fine, but in production cPanel server I has this issue

```
Vite manifest not found at: /home/???????/cart_shop/public/build/manifest.json

# With 

Missing Vite Manifest File
Did you forget to run `npm install && npm run dev`?
```

I tried to solve the problem but nothing work, I need to change the public folder and the sup folder build file place  from vite.config.js but I don't find the way to do that.

Note that: the file sequence is changed in cPanel shared server from

```
- home
    - public_html
        - cart_shop
           - Root
           - public
           - etc
```

To

```
- home
    - public_html
       - public files and folders  // I changed the index URLs too.
- cart_shop
    - Root
    - etc
```

my `vite.config.js` config is like:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

Comment: What is the node version you have? `node -v`

Comment: node : `v16.13.1` with npm: `8.14.0`

Comment: Maybe you need to change your build directory in vite config,, open vite.config.js and add under input array `buildDirectory: '../../public/build',` and see if it works.

Comment: were i can put `buildDirectory: '../public/build',` inside `export default defineConfig` or in ` plugins:` can you send me the conf sequence.

Comment: I had the same problem, and I solved it with `npm run build` command

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue only because of node version. I upgraded to the latest version and it's working properly.

For Ubuntu use n module from npm in order to upgrade node:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

To upgrade to latest version (and not current stable) version, you can use:

```
sudo n latest
```

You may need also to Fix PATH:

```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodejs-legacy     # fix /usr/bin/node
```

To undo:

```
  sudo n rm 6.0.0     # replace number with version of Node that was installed
  sudo npm uninstall -g n
```

You may need to restart your terminal to see the updated node version.

Found in [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version)

Comment: done this commands    sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n  and after that   done this command     sudo n latest   then fixed issue

Comment: Also works for Debian Bullseye (v11.6), where the stable version of the node package is only 12.22. You may need to delete/move an existing */usr/local/bin/node* and symlink /usr/local/n/versions/node/18.14.2/bin/node (or whichever version) to it. Once this is done, ``npm run build`` will work.

Answer (score 38):

In my case, I have solved this problem by doing some things.

First of all, I have made sure required npm packages are installed by running this command

```
npm install
```

After that, I have run

```
npm run build
```

To build assets and create the manifest file.

Comment: 'npm run build' solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 12):

**Type this it's works for me**

```
npm run build
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me, but it is not included in the instructions at Tailwindcss.

Answer (score 6):

This is because Laravel has `/public/build` added to the `.gitignore` file. You can either `npm install && npm run build` to install these files(as suggested by other answers) or remove `/public/build` from the `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 5):

Remove `@vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])` from the `<head>` of the file `app.blade.php` on Laravel 9. And now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

Run these commands on terminal

```
npm install --save-dev vite laravel-vite-plugin
```

Then you need to update your package.json file

```
"scripts": { "dev": "vite", "build": "vite build" }
```

Finally, you can trigger this command below to build Vite and create the manifest file.

```
npm run build
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm wanted to deploy it to a PROD environment too. I spent around 5 hours searching for answers, hoping that I can share my findings with you.

- if you're working with cPanel
- your folder structure resembles mine
- all public files are moved to `public_html`
- where is no more `public` folder in the application (all) folder

[image: folder structure]

**Solution:**

- **Duplicate the 'build' folder generated by Vite, as shown in the image below.**
  or
- **Alternatively, place only the `manifest.json` file in the `public/build` directory within the 'all' or project folder.**
- **Do not include the `manifest.json` file in the `public_html` directory with the same folder structure.**

[image: solution duplicate build]

- laravel/framework ^10.10
- vite ^4.0.0
- tailwindcss
- cPanel
- php 8.2
- googiehost

Comment: Thank you, duplication helped! I'm using hostinger, it is shared hosting too, but it has `ssh` and you can clone code via `git` by connectin to server itself https://hostinger.lt?REFERRALCODE=1MURASHKAAR72

Comment: Why would you do this when cPanel supports Git? Create a git repository within your cpanel. Push your local project to the server. Create a domain/sub-domain and point to the path including the public directory.

Comment: @Wade some free tier cpanels

Answer (score 1):

Update Node.js to its latest version: https://nodejs.org/en/

Then run `npm run dev`.

Answer (score 1):

Hy , sorry for the late comment :

if you facing this issue , you can run these command on terminal

First Command:

-> `npm install --save-dev vite laravel-vite-plugin`

Second Command:

-> `npm run build`

Your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The issue solved,

first: I try adding `publicDirectory` configration into `laravel-vite-plugin` setting in `vite.config.js` that solve the build issue but manifest still not founded.

Finally: I move all files and folders except `build` from `public` to `bublic_html` then `npm run build` and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the `manifest.json` file does exist but you're still seeing this error, make sure the permissions are good:

```bash
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R public/build/
sudo chmod g+w -R public/build/
```

Comment: Why would the `www-data` user need to write to this directory?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this:

1. `npm run build`
2. When you put `public` files inside `public_html`. Create a `public` file in the root of the domain and put the `build` folder inside it And it was done.

Answer (score 0):

**Check that your vite build was successful**.
I recently deployed a laravel + vite app on render and I was sure that the `npm run dev` step was taken. I was getting the 'manifest not found' error until I checked the logs carefully and found the build wasn't succeeding because of missing import.

Answer (score 0):

I faced an issue that displayed a similar "Vite manifest not found at:..." error message today.

In my case, this happend when I cloned my own Laravel project that I had hosted on Github on a new computer. Seems like the issue in my case was because I used Laravel Breeze and the package had some Vite dependencies.

The fix that worked for me was to run the following commands **before** running `php artisan serve`

1. `npm install`
2. `npm run build`

Again, its important to run the above commands in the same order and **restart** your Laravel server after running the commands.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to bind the **public path** with the app. You can do this in the **pubic/index.php** file and **bootstrap/app.php** file.

I always prefer to update in the **public/index.php** file. Refer to the below code.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

// Determine if the application is in maintenance mode...
if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../laravel-core/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}

// Register the Composer autoloader...
require __DIR__.'/../laravel-core/vendor/autoload.php';


// Bootstrap Laravel and handle the request...
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel-core/bootstrap/app.php';

app()->usePublicPath(__DIR__); // app bind here

$app->handleRequest(Request::capture());
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case no solutions worked and finally I find this way to:
delete
`node_modules`
directory
and then

run

```
npm install
```

and make sure you have a permission to run this command.
After that run

```
npm run build
npm run dev
```

Answer (score -1):

just go to your public folder and there is a **hot** file in that file there is a link like this **http://127.0.0.1:3000** change this link to your domain link i mean your website link

Comment: There is no such hot file in the public folder. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: firstly you need to add this code in your vite.config.js 

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
     buildDirectory: ['build',],
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
    ],
   
     server: { 
        https: true, 
        host: '0.0.0.0', 
    },

    
    
});

ANd then move all the files in public/build to public_html except build/manifest.json
and then it will work

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and I was able to resolve it by installing the `node` current stable version. In my case, the node version was `14+`, and when I upgraded to the current version which is `v16.17.0`, everything works just fine. The comments [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/failed-to-load-config-from-viteconfigjs) were helpful.

Visit the [official `node`](https://nodejs.org/) website to download and install the latest node version.

Answer (score -1):

What fixed it for me was to use a recent version of Node.

You can use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) for that:

```
nvm use 19
npm run dev
```