# Vite manifest not found in laravel using hostinger

Tags: node.js, laravel, shared-hosting

we uploaded our working laravel code on hostinger (shared servers).
Once uploaded we are having this error : Vite manifest not found at:

```
/home/.../blog/public/build/manifest.json
```

Missing Vite Manifest File

We deleted the line  `@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])` from the code.

The application works this time but `css` and `js` of login doesn't work.

Do you have any idea of the issue please ?

Best regards,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vite manifest not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73045616/vite-manifest-not-found)

Answer (score 3):

shared hosting is sucks because we don't have ssh access and have very limited choice to do. But it is really cheap. so here is what I do to upload laravel 9 with vue.js on board with vite at hostinger shared hosting.

1. run npm run build on local
2. upload all files **outside public_html**
3. copy all the data at public directory to public_html. (copy not move)

that should resolve Vite manifest not found error

Answer (score 0):

Hello There hope it's not late.

In order to use vite in your Laravel project for the installed UI files in the Authentication Module, you have to migrate to your project and run the following commands.

```
npm install

npm run dev
```

But as long as you are in production run the below command.

```
npm run build
```

Then you'll be good to go.