# npm: command not found, and failed to install it

Tags: php, laravel, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

The hosting limited terminal commands, npm, sudo, spt and more not working, while laravel project needs "npm install && npm run dev", Is there a solution, even if it manaul installation.
[Laravel Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWuK8.jpg)

I tried to install nodejs and run install npm, I tried to install npm without sudo and apt with terminal but I didn't work.

Comment: Isn't this more a question for the support or forums covering your hosting company.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vite manifest not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73045616/vite-manifest-not-found)

Comment: I guess you are trying to deploy the application, if yes then you should build the assets using `npm run build` before uploading the files to the hosting.

Comment: If I write npm In terminal it says npm not found

Comment: You should communicate with your host support and ask them to run `npm` commands themselves if it is possible. Because most times shared hosting firms limit customers to run some commands via terminal.