# Laravel 10: Vite manifest not found at: //manifest.json

Tags: php, laravel, vite

I am using Laravel after a long time and latest version introduced "Vite". Locally I could run `rpm run dev` but on remote shared hosting when I ran `npm run build`, it still gives an error:

```
Vite manifest not found at: /home/pknemyay/innercomforts.net/public/build/manifest.json (View: /.../resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php) (View: /.../resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php)
```

How do I fix it?

**Blade**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Inner Comforts</title>
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <!-- Styles -->
    {{-- <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
    <meta name="robots" content="max-image-preview:large">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
```

**vite Config**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

**Package JSON**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.6.1",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.8.0",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you have 14.5k rep, but don't know you need to post all of the relevant code for us to help? Post your package.json, vite.conf, and blade file.

Comment: @bassxzero I am sorry for this. I had not made config changes and used default hence I had not shared. Anyways, the question is updated

Comment: @Volatil3 Have you checked that is there manifest file on root?

Comment: You can simply do is to copy that file and add into public folder which resolves this error as it's looking for the file which is generated through build but on root.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vite manifest not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73045616/vite-manifest-not-found)

Comment: @KamranAllana Thanks for the reply, someone on the linked question said to remove `public/build` from the `.gitignore` which I did, and now when run  it gives error: ` @ build /
> vite build

(node:2746856) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: wasm memory
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)`

Comment: Which server you're deploying on ? cpanel based?

Comment: @KamranAllana Yes cPanel based. I rather sorted this out by pushing `public/build` on git and then pulled it on the remote server, worked like charm

Comment: That's cool! Have a great day